# Button Changes it position when Keyboard gets displayed in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am trying to do following Design

[image: Valid XHTML]

My XML Code is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/patientid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/speak"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/patientidhint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/speak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/patientid"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="speak"
        android:text="@string/speak" 
        tools:context=".CreatingPatientFolder"
        />
    
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTextMatches"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/speak" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_Submit"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I run this project it gets displayed as follow

[image: Valid XHTML]

So can any one please tell me why my button is getting shift upwards also please help me to remove this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why the button is moved is because your list is empty, you have enough room to move the button and the button is not bellow the edit text, therefore it can overlap it.

There is a property in your manifest called "[windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode%29)". This property specifies how the soft keyboard should behave.

You could use:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing
```

Answer (score 0):

#### add this in ur Button:

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

i did not test . May be Solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sam But when I add
android:layout_marginTop does not help me
since The issue arise only when Keyboard gets displayed onto the screen as soon as I close the soft keyboard My button goes to the orignal position

Answer (score 0):

One More thing that helped me was the change of theme in the Manifest file to NoActionBar and FullScreen (In case you don't want to use the ActionBar like me).

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```