# android virtual keyboard changes the position of button and place it over edittext on focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have created an app in which there is an edittext to take input from user and below it there is an button. When the user click or focus on the edittext to input something the button position is changed by the keyboard and it overlap the edittext. I have tried the solution provided in
**[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167044/button-changes-it-position-when-keyboard-gets-displayed-in-android)** answer. But it doesn't helped me

i have used this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing
```

please someone hep....

**Edit:**
This is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true" 
   android:background="#ffffff"
   tools:context=".MyAds"
   android:id="@+id/TestAd"
  >


<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
     >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtLoanAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtLoanAmount"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoanAmount"
        android:ems="10"

        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtRateOfInterest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtRateOfInerest"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtRateOfInerest"
        android:ems="10"

        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRateOfInerest"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtLoanAmount"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtLoanAmount"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Rate of Inerest"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLoanAmount"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Enter Loan Amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLoanTenure"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtRateOfInterest"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Loan Tenure (In Months)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtLoanTenure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoanTenure"
        android:ems="10"

        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEMI"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalculateEmi"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLoanAmorSchedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEMI"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_states"
        android:text="Loan Amortization Schedule" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/initqube" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculateEmi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtLoanTenure"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_states"
        android:text="Calculate EMI" />

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/MyAdView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx" >
     </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please show your xml layout here...

Comment: @umair.ali i have showed my layout xml...

Answer (score 1):

my issue has been solved...

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculateEmi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtLoanTenure"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_states"
        android:text="Calculate EMI" />
```

After removing the

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

from the button property. Everything works like a charm...

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

in the `Android Manifest XML` file for your `Activity`.